# Why can't I access Windows from Grub after installing Ubuntu?

Tags: 11.10, grub2, windows, dual-boot

I'm new to Ubuntu and just installed it on my HP Compaq nx5000. I dual-boot installed with Windows XP. When I boot, it goes to the grub bootloader. At the bottom of the Grub list it says boot Windows XP professional. But when I select the last one and press enter, no matter how many times I try, it either loads Ubuntu or goes back to the bootloader.

Comment: Please run Boot-Repair's "Recommended repair", and indicate the URL that will appear. It will help us understand your problem.

Comment: Can you please post the output of the following commands: `sudo os-prober|grep -i windows` and `grep -B 2 chainloader /boot/grub/grub.cfg`?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), Boot-Repair is a one-click solution that detects currently installed operating systems and updates grub configuration.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu open up the Terminal (if you don't know how, open the Dash launcher and type terminal).
In the terminal window type this in:

```
sudo update-grub2
```

It will ask for your user password (the one you use to login to Ubuntu). Type it in and press enter.
After that some text will come up in the terminal (it should be pretty similar to the text you get on the grub boot menu screen). After a minute, when the command stops restart and try loading Windows XP again.  Tell us if it works.

Comment: no it does the same thing again :(

Comment: it only shows "_" without quotes flickering at the upper left screen and back to grub boot loader

Comment: plz i really need help...

Comment: Try running the command again, and copy and paste the text that comes out.
Also, open your home folder and try to see if your windows hard drive shows up under "devices".